# Representing vector as a column vector with respect to two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have never done anything like this and the only examples I can find online basically tell me how to do the change of basis for "change-of-coordinates matrix from $B$ to $C$". If anyone is able to help me solve this, I would be very grateful. I really don't know where to start.

This is the problem:

*Represent the vector as a column vector with respect to each of the two bases.*
$$..\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{r}
3\\
-1
\end{array}\end{pmatrix}\quad B_{1}=\left<\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{r}
1\\
-1
\end{array}\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{r}
1\\
1
\end{array}\end{pmatrix}\right>,\;\quad B=\left<\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{r}
1\\
2
\end{array}\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{r}
1\\
3
\end{array}\end{pmatrix}\right>$$..

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use mathjax rather than images. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start. Also, what attempts have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: They just want you to represent the given vector as a linear combination of the basis vectors.  Do you understand what that means?

Comment: @saulspatz I know what it means but don't know how to find it so I can represent it :/

Comment: Start by writing down what it means, in terms of the specific vector and one of the bases.  I think you'll be able to solve it then, but if you can't, add what you have done to your question, and explain what the specific difficulty is.

Comment: @saulspatz my main problem is I don't know what steps to take in order to represent the vector as a column vector with respect to two bases. Do I multiply them? I believe my teacher said to multiply the two matrices but I just can't remember and what I read online seems to say different things.

Comment: I see.  You only represent a vector with respect to one basis at a time.  There are two different problems in the question, as I read it.  There aren't any matrices to multiply here.  Can you post the exact statement of the problem?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I just added - thank you!

Comment: It's just what I thought.  The "each of" means represent it in terms of each of the bases, one after the other.

Comment: Do I multiply the vector times the first base, and then again times the second base to represent it with respect to each of the bases?

Comment: @saulspatz thank you very much I appreciate it. I have a test on this tomorrow so trying to run through practice problems but my book is still at school

Comment: @saulspatz can you let me know where you upload it? I'm new to this site so unsure if you would put it in the comments or a separate post?

Comment: @saulspatz I actually just realized you'll probably private message me the steps? I'm not really sure but thank you very much for your help in advance either way.

Comment: No, I'm posting an answer, and as I imagine you've already seen, when anybody writes anything on one of your questions, you'll get pinged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused.  When you talk about the matrix, I take you to mean a matrix whose columns are the basis vectors.  In the case of $B_1$ that would be $$M :=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$  If we multiply a vector $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ by $M$, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}a+b\\-a+b\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Expressing $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors means to find $a$ and $b$ such that $$\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\tag1$$
That is, you don't want to multiply the given vector by the matrix; you want to find a matrix which, when multiplied by the vector, produces the given vector.  In other words, you need to solve $(1)$ for $a$ and $b$.  This simply means solving a system of two linear equations in two unknowns.

Comment: Thank you so much! Answered my question completely.

Comment: @strugglingincs123 If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark.  That way it leaves the unsolved queue (and I get a little more rep :-)).

Comment: done! thanks again:)